# Email->from in CakePhp doesn't function good.

Tags: email, cakephp

I use

```
$email->from('contact@domain.com');
```

But the email in my inbox arrives as "username@host411.hostmonster.com"

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP is actually using the the PHP mail function. so you need to check your mail settings in php.ini.

Moreover, using from() is very unstable, because of many unspam systems. i'd suggest you using replyTo() instead.

More about CakePHP mailing functions: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1284/Class-Attributes-and-Variables